# winmain() function / c++

Tags: c++, return-value, winmain

can you please explain to me the significance of this statement generally written at the end of the `WinMain()` function:

```
   return (int) msg.wParam;
```

Im used to ending my console applications with `return 0;` is it wrong for windows applications?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you want to return the value that was passed to PostQuitMessage().

Comment: ok, but why is there `(int)`? is it some kind of casting wParam to integer?

Comment: or making it clear to the compiler?

Comment: wParam is not an int, cast required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) loop stops after receiving a [`WM_QUIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window message which is normally issued after a call to the [`PostQuitMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which describes its `nExitCode` parameter as *the application exit code*.

If you want to respect the intent of the person who invoked the `PostQuitMessage()` function, you should return that value from main.  This is what you are doing when you return the `wParam` retrieved from the last invocation of `GetMessage()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the `WinMain()` docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx):

> Terminate the message loop when it receives a `WM_QUIT` message. At that
>   point, your `WinMain` should exit the application, returning the value
>   passed in the `WM_QUIT` message's `wParam` parameter. If `WM_QUIT` was
>   received as a result of calling `PostQuitMessage`, the value of `wParam`
>   is the value of the `PostQuitMessage` function's `nExitCode` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

From [the first hit of a Google search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Your WinMain should initialize the application, display its main
>   window, and enter a message retrieval-and-dispatch loop that is the
>   top-level control structure for the remainder of the application's
>   execution. Terminate the message loop when it receives a WM_QUIT
>   message. At that point, your WinMain should exit the application,
>   returning the value passed in the WM_QUIT message's wParam parameter.
>   If WM_QUIT was received as a result of calling PostQuitMessage, the
>   value of wParam is the value of the PostQuitMessage function's
>   nExitCode parameter. For more information, see Creating a Message
>   Loop.